# JSmooth - After creating exe(using JSmooth) the Runtime.getRuntime() is not working

Tags: java, jsmooth

I have created a small program where I need the install location of a program. I am using this in windows. So I written a small program with the below line which gives the the path of the installed software

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("REG QUERY "+ location +" /v "+ key);
```

After this I created a jar file and it works fine. But when I wrap that jar file using jsmooth and create an exe out of it and when I run the exe the above line returns nothing. I am not sure why it is happening, any ideas?

```
Summary :
Jar is working fine
Same jar if wrapped and become exe does not work.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont know wether my experience can relate, but i had a somewhat similar experience with jsmooth. my jar was working fine (it was a bluetooth program) but after wrapping it, i kept getting a "noclassdef" error. my problem was that i had packaged everything in my program as a jar using eclispse. but i later generated a "dist" folder using netbeans and this time during class selection in jsmooth, i saw that it had included javax.bluetooth.localdevice which was causing the classnotfound error.
sorry if the answer isnt very clear, this is the first time am answering here